# What does "all devices are files" mean?

Tags: linux, file, device

I heard someone say that in Linux "all devices are files."  What does that mean? My understanding of a file is that it is a logical location on disk to which bytes are written and from which bytes are read.  A device to my knowledge is just any physical piece of hardware... somewhat unrelated to files.  Can someone explain this statement to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linux *treats* every device as if it were a file. That is, you interact with a device programmatically in exactly the same way you'd interact with a file:

- You specify the device via a path, usually under the `/dev` directory.
- You begin by "opening" the device, just as you'd open a file, which gives you a file descriptor.
- You can perform `ioctl` (input/output control) operations on the file descriptor.
- You can send and/or retrieve data by writing and/or reading the file descriptor.
- You "close" the device when you're finished using it.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the actual details of a device are abstracted away, such that an application can treat it as a file for IO purposes.

E.g. a serial port may be implemented in hardware in many different ways, but the operating system hides that so that an application can read and write to and from the device exactly as if it were reading and writing a file.